# Why $\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|=1}}\|Ax\|\geq\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|\leq1}}\|Ax\|?$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space.

For  $A\in\mathcal{L}(E)$, I want to show that
$$\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|=1}}\|Ax\|=\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|\leq1}}\|Ax\|.$$
Clearly, since
$$\{\|Ax\|;\;x\in E,\,\|x\|=1\}\subset \{\|Ax\|;\;x\in E,\,\|x\|\leq1\},$$
then
$$\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|=1}}\|Ax\|\leq\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|\leq1}}\|Ax\|.$$

> Why 
>   $$\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|=1}}\|Ax\|\geq\sup_{\substack{x\in E,\\ \|x\|\leq1}}\|Ax\|?$$

Comment: You need to add the condition $E \ne \{0\}$, otherwise the left supremum ranges over the empty set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: note that if $\|x\|\le1$, then $\|Au\|\ge\|Ax\|$ where $u=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$.